# How do I check if a text variable is null, false, or less than 0?

Tags: php, if-statement, filter-input

I am kind of new to PHP but I was having an issue. I have a PHP form that I submit. The assignment instructs that I must use a filter_input to check if the values are null. However, when i use the if/else statements it keeps stopping on the 2nd NULL option even if I input words. I check using var_dump and the variable is false. Why is the False message not coming up?

```
$product_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'product_name');
$quantity = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quantity',FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$unit_price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'unit_price',FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
var_dump($quantity);

//validate product_name
if ( $product_name == NULL) {
    $error_message = 'Please enter a valid product name'; 
//validate quantity
} else if ( $quantity == NULL)  {
    $error_message = 'Quantity is null'; 
} else if ( $quantity == FALSE ) {
    $error_message = 'Quantity must be a valid number.'; 
} else if ( $quantity <= 0 ) {
    $error_message = 'Quantity must be greater than zero.'; 
//unit_price
} else if ( $unit_price == NULL ) {
    $error_message = 'Unit Price is null';
} else if ( $unit_price <= 0 ) {
    $error_message = 'Unit Price must be greater than zero.';
// set error message to empty string if no invalid entries
} else {
    $error_message = ''; 
}

// if an error message exists, go to the purchase2.php page
if ($error_message != '') {
    include('purchase2.php');
    exit(); 
}
```

I expected that the FALSE message would come up but it keeps stopping at NULL and saying Quantity is null.

Comment: use `is_null()` to check for null and `is_bool()` to check for boolean

Comment: `$quantity == "NULL) ` ?? No need for the `"` and it blows the compilation as well. See the syntax highlighting

Answer (score 1):

By default, `filter_input` will return `null` if the key is not set or `false` if the filter fails. Unless someone has manipulated the form code before submitting it or you forgot/misnamed one of the inputs, those keys will always be present, so none of the filters should ever return null.

But since `null` is a falsey value, you can evaluate both possibilities the same way and it doesn't really matter which one it was.

If that key is missing from $_POST for some reason and `filter_input` returns `null`, then they didn't enter a valid value, and if it's *not* missing from $_POST but it's invalid and `filter_input` returns `false`, then they didn't enter a valid value. Either way they should get the same message.

```
if (!$product_name) {
    $error_message = 'Please enter a valid product name';
} else if ($quantity === null || $quantity === false) {
    $error_message = 'Quantity must be a valid number.';
} else if ($quantity <= 0 ) {
    $error_message = 'Quantity must be greater than zero.';
} else if ($unit_price === null || $unit_price === false) {
    $error_message = 'Unit Price must be a valid number';
} else if ($unit_price <= 0 ) {
    $error_message = 'Unit Price must be greater than zero.';
} else {
    $error_message = '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I am pretty new to this so it helps. Is it possible to have a different message for if someone leaves it blank than if someone inputs a non-integer, or negative number? In the assignment, it specifically says it has to have a message for NULL, message for non-integer, and a message for negative inputs in quantity.

Comment: I see. Well, unfortunately leaving it blank still won't give you a null result from `filter_input`. You'll get `false` whether they entered something non-numeric or nothing at all, so you can't really tell the difference at that point. If you need to check for an empty entry, I think you'll need to do it before filtering.

Comment: Ah okay. Makes sense. Thanks a lot!